# How to access class in Unity.DemoTeam namespace?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I added hair system package to the project.(The package created by the unity demo team)

https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/com.unity.demoteam.hair

I tried to access the class in the downloaded package, but the namespace could not be found. Is there any way to access it?

[The class i tried to access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyh74.png)

[namespace is not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSGPo.png)

Comment: Where is the package in your folder structure or package manager?

Comment: It was downloaded from the package manager, it is visible in the Packages menu of the Project window just like the Unity UI.

Comment: Shot in the dark, are you defining your own assembly definitions (to support unit testing, maybe?) That's the primary thing that's caused those issues for me - add a package and forget to include the folder in the assembly definition.